# Android: Issue on onSingleTapUp and onDoubleTap

Tags: android

On single click onSingleTapUp function executes properly and while on doubleclick both onSingleTapUp and onDoubleTap executes.

```
mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) 
            {

            }


            @Override
            public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) 
            {
                cameracontrolslayout.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.GONE);
                presetcontrolslayout.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.GONE);

                ViewFLipperButtonsLayout.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.VISIBLE);
                    ptzcontrolslayout.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.VISIBLE);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent arg0) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                cameracontrolslayout.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.VISIBLE);
                presetcontrolslayout.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.VISIBLE);


            return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) 
            {
                return true;
            }

       });
```

can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `onSingleTapUp` why not use [onSingleTapConfirmed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html#onSingleTapConfirmed%28android.view.MotionEvent%29), however you layout will be visible at the time of taping down.